# nil is not a symbol when uploading file using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

i have searched a lot. 
I'm facing this error
[image]

Create method in Controller is

def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @category.save
    format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @category, status: :created, location: @category }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

My Form is

```
<%= form_for @category, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<% if @category.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from   being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :description %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :description%>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

When i select the file to upload and click submit button not proceed

My Uploader is

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'carrierwave/processing/rmagick'
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

#Include RMagick or MiniMagick support
include CarrierWave::RMagick

# Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
storage :file

# This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
def store_dir
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def scale(width, height)
 # do something
end

# Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [80, 80]
  end

end
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your CarrierWave uploader class (the one mounted the :image attribute). It would help if you paste the code of your uploader.

Comment: THanks for response, i have added the uploader, plz guide me where i am wrong

Comment: Your uploader seems right. We actually even tried in our project and it worked fine. The error you get means that a given processor to run is nil (instead of :resize_to_fill). Are you sure the code you pasted is of the relevant uploader causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have Create the new project, apply everything in the same way and its working, still don't know why this error occurred but now i have no problem.